# How to use Google's closure quadtree

Tags: javascript, google-closure

Looking at Google's closures quadtree:

http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_QuadTree.html

I am unable to find the methods that give it any more useful properties than a hashmap (unless, I manually walked the tree). So, surely I'm missing something? Where are the functions like nearest searches, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The quad tree has minimal usage (that is none that I know of), so there hasn't been much investment in it.  You will have to add any additional functionality you would like yourself.